# Amplify How to restore backend definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify

I'm trying to pull a backend environment from amplify, but when i use the command `amplify pull --appId 1234 --envName test` it returns the message: Environment test not found. If this backend already exists, try restoring it's definition in your `team-provider-info.json` file. The backend already exists.

After this i tried the same command with `--restore` flag, but this doesn't work either. So, how can i restore my backend definition so i be able to use amplify pull?

[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a cloudformation permission my role hadn't. The error message could be more precise i guess.

Answer (score 3):

This could be an issue with your aws profiles , probably you are using another profile/keys or try running **aws configure** to do a right setup.

Comment: Yes this was issue for me as Carlos says. 

I updated the profile in amplify/.config/local-aws-info.json and re-run pull and it worked